# Relationship between two tables with EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables, both of which have embeddedIds:

I want to create a mapping between TableA and Table2 (OneToOne), where field1 of TableAId gets mapped to field1 of TableBId and field2 of TableAId gets mapped to field2 of TableBId. Please advise on how can I achieve this relationship. Any kind of solution (@JoinTable, @JoinColumns) is okay.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class TableA {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableAId id;

    private String name;

    // Other columns, getters, setters...
}

@Embeddable
public class TableAId implements Serializable {
    private Long field1;
    private Long field2;

    // Getters, setters, constructors...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
public class TableB {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableBId id;

    private String name;

    // Other columns, getters, setters...
}

@Embeddable
public class TableBId implements Serializable {
    private Long field1;
    private Long field2;

    // Getters, setters, constructors...
}
```

Comment: Do `TableAId` and `TableBId` need to be different classes?

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement.